# HasMany - save association data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need help. I have a two tables `business_departments` and `companies` with association type `hasMany`.

I need to modify companies list consisting in the department. Code was generated via *bake*, after that I modified it.

**Controller.**

```
$businessDepartment = $this->BusinessDepartments->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Companies']
]);
$companies = $this->BusinessDepartments->Companies->find('list')->where([
    'Companies.active' => true, 
    'Companies.type IS NOT' => 'service', 
    'OR' => [
        'business_department_id IS NULL',
        'business_department_id' => $id
    ]
])->distinct('Companies.id');
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    debug($this->request->getData());
    $businessDepartment = $this->BusinessDepartments->patchEntity($businessDepartment, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Companies']]);
    debug($businessDepartment);
    if ($this->BusinessDepartments->save($businessDepartment)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The business department has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The business department could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
$this->set(compact('businessDepartment', 'companies'));
```

**Entity.**

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'name' => true,
    'companies' => true
];
```

**Table**

```
$this->hasMany('Companies', [
    'foreignKey' => 'business_department_id',
    // Tried it
    /*'dependent' => true,
    'cascadeCallbacks' => true,
    'saveStrategy' => 'replace'*/
]);
```

**template.**

```
echo $this->Form->control('companies._ids', ['options' => $companies, 'multiple' => true, 'class' => 'multiple-find']);
```

First save with added companies is success, but when I tried to modify companies list (And if try to save without changes) I get error.

Can I save via `*._ids` or I need to make a custom code for it?

**Below** `debug($this->request->getData())`

```
[
    'name' => 'Office',
    'companies' => [
        '_ids' => [
            (int) 0 => '21',
            (int) 1 => '29'
        ]
    ]
]
```

But after patchEntity, instead of searching for companies and changing the business_department_id fields in them, patchEntity tries to create new companies and displays an error. Below is a fragment of screenshot.
[`debug($businessDepartment)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaNnd.png) and [screenshot page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvwhA.png)

Thank you. I hope for quick answer.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please post the complete message including the related stacktrace (copied from the log files). Also please always include your debugging results. Thanks! If you're talking about the error flash message, then make sure that you debug your entity _after_ `save()` has been called too.

Comment: @ndm, Thank, I'll modify question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone will come in handy!

> you have validation errors in your company related data, thats why you
>   cant save it, if you want to just use `_ids` as save try clearing
>   `companies` field in your `$businessDepartment` i.e.
>
> ```
> $businessDepartment->unsetProperty('companies');
> ```
>
> before `patchEntity`
>
> [Graziel](https://discourse.cakephp.org/u/Graziel)